# How to slice a date so, i can compare with month and day only?

Tags: php, mysql, continuous-integration, pyrocms

I have a problem with date .
I have a Birth date eg. 1993-06-01 in database. And now i want to compare with now date so, I can pop up the birthday message. How is this possible to compare with only month and day field. Especially in query so i can attached  their name with  birthday message
Used framework Pyrocms.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230738/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-years-in-php

Comment: Doesn't it seem a little implausible that no one has encountered this problem before and perhaps thought to provide a solution that might benefit all mankind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP just use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('1993-06-01');
$date2 = new DateTime();
if ($date1->format('m-d') === $date2->format('m-d')) {
  // send the birthday message
}
```

If you want to do this in SQL then use `MONTH()` and `DAY()`.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(`date_column`) = " . $date->format('n') . " AND DAY(`date_column`) = " . $date->format('j');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works . But i want to compare in where condition in sql

Comment: @babulshrestha I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare with month, you have this function in mysql:

```
MONTH(date)
```

That returns the month (in numbers 1 .. 12)

You also have

```
MONTHNAME(date)
```

that returns the month in string ('January', ' February', ...)

For the day you have:

```
DAYNAME(date) --> returns ('Sunday','Monday' ...)
DAYOFWEEK(date)  --> returns  (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday)
```

You can look for all the date time functions in this link [MySql dev](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)